# image slider with margin animation breaking on screen resize (NO slider plugin used)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a fluid JQuery slider without using any sort of slider plugin and media queries (just CSS and jquery). Most solutions involve a slider plugin and media queries. For educational purposes, I am trying to do without.

I am using margin animation to move the slides (I don't know if it's the best approach to achieve the responsiveness).
Unfortunately, this is not responsive as the slide widths are fixed in the css.

please see code below for possible fix. for the pictures, I just created a 650px by 350px rectangle on paint as placeholder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slider</title>
        <style>
            *{
                margin: 0;padding: 0;
            }
            html{
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            *, *:before, *:after {
                -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
                -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
                box-sizing: inherit;
            }
            .carousel{
                border: 2px solid #000;
                max-width: 650px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .carousel__canvas{
                width: 3900px;
            }
            .carousel__item{
                float: left;
                list-style-type: none; 
            }
            .carousel__item img{
                width: 100%
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel__canvas">
                <li class="carousel__item"><img src="p1.png" alt="First Image"></li>
                <li class="carousel__item"><img src="p2.png" alt="Second Image"></li>
                <li class="carousel__item"><img src="p3.png" alt="Third Image"></li>
                <li class="carousel__item"><img src="p4.png" alt="Fourth Image"></li>
                <li class="carousel__item"><img src="p5.png" alt="Fifth Image"></li>
                <li class="carousel__item"><img src="p1.png" alt="First Image"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var currentSlide = 1;
        var $carousel__item = $('.carousel__item');
        var numSlides = $carousel__item.length;
        var slideWidth = $carousel__item.width();
        var $viewport = $('.carousel');
        var $slideContainer = $viewport.find('.carousel__canvas');
        var $slide = $slideContainer.find('.carousel__item');
        var trasitionTime = 500;
        var slideViewTime = 3500;
        var interval;
        slideContainerWidth = slideWidth * numSlides;

        function startCarousel(){
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                if(numSlides>1){
                    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left':'-='+slideWidth+'px'},     trasitionTime,function(){
                            if(++currentSlide === numSlides){
                                $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left':'0'},0);
                                currentSlide = 1;
                            }
                        });
                }
            },slideViewTime);
        }

        function stopCarousel(){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        $viewport.on('mouseover',stopCarousel).on('mouseleave', startCarousel);
        startCarousel();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use static width. You can use percentages always and an "height:auto" in css to make it responsive !!!

Comment: I tried using percentages but I don't know how to put the values in order. When i set the .carousel__item to 100%, breaks the float.